# HTML - Fixed header & footer, horizontally centered layout

Tags: html, css, wrapper

Lets assume I have the following layout (image 1). 
I have a header always at the top, a footer always at the bottom. And the content should fill the space left between the header and the footer by 100% (image 2).
Moreover I want the content of the header, content and footer to be centered horizontally, it use only 550px (image 3).

**Image 1 :**

[image: image 1]!

**Image 2 :**

[image: image 2.]!

**Image 3 :**

[image: image 3]!

Can't think of any way how to achieve this using pure css. 
I can't manage to merge fixed header/footer with centered wrapper.
Any ideas would be appreciated ! Thanks

Comment: Did you actually try writing some code?

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: simply make three `div` with header, footer, and body and use `text-align:center` to center the content

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yes I tried some code. I was able to make fixed header/footer and horizontal centered content but not both together. 
@Amit singh : `text-align:center` just align text, I want everything centered. I manage to do it with below answers. Thank you for your help;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add an inner element that specifies the width of the element. So something like this would work for what you're trying to achieve:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <header id="page-header">
        <div class="inner">
            Centered
        </div>
    </header>
    <div id="page-content">
        <div class="inner">
           Centered
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer id="page-footer">
        <div class="inner">
            Centered
        </div>
    </footer>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#page-header,
#page-footer {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    background: #ccc;
}

#page-header {
    top: 0;
    height: 100px;
}

#page-footer {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 75px;
}

#page-content {
    padding: 100px 0 75px;
}

.inner {
    width: 550px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    background: orange;
}
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jxn1r1a4/)

Comment: I think it is better to use stack overflow's code snippet feature instead of providing link to jsfiddle.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but I still prefer jsFiddle. Personal preference, I suppose.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, it's exactly what I was looking for. Perfert ! 
I still have a little problem with mobile phone/tablet where the fixed header/footer aren't always shown. 
Morevover how to show on these devices only header/content/footer without vertical border on left and right ?

Answer (score 2):

that's actually pretty easy: https://jsfiddle.net/xpp6a6rf/

the things you might want to edit are the `height` and `line-height` of the `header`, `footer` and `.inner` elements and the `max-width` of `.page`

be sure to use `box-sizing:border-box`

Comment: I think it is better to use stack overflow's code snippet feature instead of providing link to jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

if I got your question correct:

dummy structure - HTML

```
<header>
 <div class="container">
  HEADER CONTENT
 </div>
</header>
<section>
 <div class="container orange">
   content
 </div>
</section>
<footer>
 <div class="container">
   footer content
 </div>
</footer>
```

---

CSS for above code

```
body {padding-top:50px;padding-bottom:100px;}
header,footer {background:#D2D2D2;position:fixed;left:0;right:0;width:100%;}
header {top:0;height:50px;}
.container {width:550px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;}
.orange {background:orange;}
footer {height:100px;bottom:0;}
```